# Downloading In Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I was told before using the Tor browser that it is not advisable to download in Tor browser.  My question is once I have downloaded a Tor file (A pdf file or a video file) and then restart the browser session and then use the downloaded file, will I still have a possibility of being detected? Or if I shut down the browser and am still connected to the internet will I be detected?
If the Q sounds a little outdated... Sorry. Am a first time user....

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding the problem lies in the possibility that the document that you downloaded contains some code that will cause your computer to connect to the internet directly and not through Tor. A lot of documents types (especially pdfs, word or excel documents) provide a lot of functionality to the creator of the document that you might not be aware of. This could be used to make a connection from your computer to some server, thus disclosing your real ip. A more detailed explanation can be found for example [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39863/downloading-files-using-tor).

Comment: @user3197916: If you want to thank another user for an answer, please use the upvote button. See also [why voting is important](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).